# (JAVA) Inheritance from user inputted values keeps getting null

Tags: java, inheritance, user-input

I'm very new to java so my code might be very inefficient or downright wrong. I'm really sorry if this was a stupid question but my problem is when I print `mgr.getDetails()` all the user inputted values from `Employee`  are null.

Here are the codes:

Employee:

```
public class Employee {

    protected int ID;

    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String middleName;
    protected double salary;
    protected String birthDate;

    public String getDetails(){
        return "ID: " + String.format("%03d", ID) + "\nName: " + firstName + ", " + lastName + ", " + middleName + "\nBirthdate: " + birthDate + 
                "\nSalary: " + String.format("%,.2f",salary);
    }
    
    public void setDetails(int ID, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, String birthDate, double salary){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

Manager:

```
public class Manager extends Employee{

    protected String department;

    
  
    @Override
    public String getDetails(){
        return super.getDetails() + "\nDepartment: " + department;
    }   
    public void setDetails(String department){
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

MainClass:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Employee e = new Employee();
        Manager mgr = new Manager();
        
        System.out.println("Enter ID: ");
        int ID = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
        String firstName = input.nextLine();
       
        
        System.out.println("Enter Middle Name: ");
        String middleName = input.nextLine();
    
        
        System.out.println("Enter last Name: ");
        String lastName = input.nextLine();
        
        
        System.out.println("Enter Salary: ");
        double salary = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
     
        System.out.println("Enter Birthdate: ");
        String birthDate = input.nextLine();
        e.setDetails(ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary);
        
        System.out.println("Enter Department: ");
        String department = input.nextLine();
        mgr.setDetails(department);
        
        System.out.println(mgr.getDetails());
        input.close();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting the details on an instance of `Employee`, `e`. But you print the values from an instance of `Manager`, `mgr`. You should see a non-null department, do you?

Comment: Yes, I do see a non-null department. I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: Do you understand that you have two distinct objects? That the properties other than department are being set on the first object, `e`, and that you are displaying the second object `mgr`, so you don't see any of the other properties?

Comment: I'd suggest that you read an OO tutorial, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Comment: The question is okay, but it could be even better if you would shorten your code example to the basic stuff. For the purpose of your question, it is not really important how you input the values for the employee, or if the employee has a birthdate or middle name. Keep on learning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You seamed to be at the beginning of a great developer career, and even thought the answer is very simple, I will use it to give you some guidelines how to approach problem-solving.

**Try always to resolve your problem with the "pen and paper", meaning the first thing is to understand the problem and resolve it manually. Only then you can pour it into a programming code.**

First, the strict answer to your original posted question: The `mgr` and `e` objects are two separate objects and the inheritance relationship between the `Manager` and `Employee` classes is not enough for the effect you are expecting.

And now some proposals how to get to the solution that fits your needs.

If you like to continue with the *Java Inheritance*, then you have to set super and subclass properly. Using *constructor* method and proper setters and getters is highly recommended.

```java
Employee e = new Employee(ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary);
Manager mgr = new Manager(ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary, department);  // Now, I am a manager !!!

System.out.println(mgr.getDetails());
```

For this to work, the `Employee` and `Manager` classes should look like:

```java
public class Employee {

    protected int ID;

    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
    protected String middleName;
    protected double salary;
    protected String birthDate;

    public Employee(int ID, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, String birthDate, double salary) {
        setDetails(ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary);
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return String.format("ID: %03d\nName: %s, %s, %s\nBirthdate: %s\nSalary: %,.2f", ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary);
    }
    
    public void setDetails(int ID, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, String birthDate, double salary) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

```java
public class Manager extends Employee {

    protected String department;

    public Manager(int ID, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, String birthDate, double salary, String department) {
        super(ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary);
        this.department = department;
    }
  
    @Override
    public String getDetails() {
        return super.getDetails() + "\nDepartment: " + department;
    }

}
```

Even thought this might work, it is also showing that in this particular case the *Inheritance* is probably not the best pattern to use.

How about this way? Let's change the `Manager` class a bit:

```java
public class Manager {

    protected Employee employee;
    protected String department;

    public Manager(Employee employee, String department) {
        this.employee = employee;
        this.department = department;
    }
  
    @Override
    public String getDetails(){
        return employee.getDetails() + "\nDepartment: " + department;
    }

}
```

Then you can use it in the following way. It looks like you can easily promote an employee to a manager ;-)

```java
Employee e = new Employee(ID, firstName, lastName, middleName, birthDate, salary);
Manager mgr = new Manager(e, department);  // Now, I am a manager !!!

System.out.println(mgr.getDetails());
```

Hope it helps. Keep on learning ;-)